# Android InApp Purchase issue "Error while retrieving information from server.[RPC:S-7:AEC-0] "

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Currently i'm working on InApp Purchase for android app, done with the coding and testing it with gmail tester account, after i give all credit/debit card details for purchase of items, and pressed "save" button, there comes an error message `Error while retrieving information from server.[RPC:S-7:AEC-0]`. 
      To solve this i cleared all data and cache from playstore and rebooted the device. Still the issue remains the same. If anybody faced this type of issue please do help me...

Answer (score 0):

Note that only cards with a US billing address can be added on the Wallet app.

Go to Settings and tap Credit and debit cards.
Tap the + sign, on the top-right corner, and enter your card's information. If you see a camera icon in the "Card number" field, you can take a picture of your card's number instead of entering it manually.
Tap Add credit or debit card.
Reference:
https://support.google.com/wallet/troubleshooter/3222463?hl=en&ref_topic=3209985#ts=2896139,2896157